# Only show content for selected table row

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have the following markup:

```
<table class="tableM">
  <tr  class="accordion">
    <th>Hello</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tableMCell">
    Hi!
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="accordion">
    <th>Goodbye</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tableMCell">
    Cya!
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Which I am applying an accordion effect to when a user clicks one of the headers using:

```
$(function () {
  $(".tableM tr:not(.accordion)").hide();
  $(".tableM tr:first-child").show();
  $(".tableM tr.accordion").click(function () {
    $(this).nextAll("tr").fadeToggle(200);
  });
});
```

This is working fine to an extent however when clicking the top header i.e. `<th>Hello</th>` the desired effect is that it only shows the next `tr` containing the `Hi!` message. However it is also revealing the content under the `<th>Goodbye</th>` row as well? How can I resolve this so that onclicking either row it just shows their respective content and not all content?

Comment: Just a small point: Note that you are missing THEAD and TBODY - not sure if these are vital but jQuery can be picky...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply use `.next()` instead of `.nextAll()`

```
$(this).next("tr").fadeToggle(200);
```

The reason is `.nextAll()` will select **all** of the next `<tr>`s instead of just selecting the next one.

```js
$(function() {
  $(".tableM tr:not(.accordion)").hide();
  $(".tableM tr:first-child").show();
  $(".tableM tr.accordion").click(function() {
    $(this).next("tr").fadeToggle(200);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="tableM">
  <tr class="accordion">
    <th>Hello</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tableMCell">
      Hi!
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="accordion">
    <th>Goodbye</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tableMCell">
      Cya!
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

To toggle the other accordions back you need to get them and fade them out

```
$(this).next("tr").fadeToggle(200) // this is what you have now
          .end().siblings('.accordion').next("tr").fadeOut(200); 
          // ^ this will select the other accordions and toggle their content.
```

How it works.

```
$(this).next("tr").fadeToggle(200) // toggles the next accordion content, the selector is now .next('tr') meaning the content
       .end() // this returns the selector one step back to $(this) / the tr you clicked on
       .siblings('.accordion') // gets all tr with the class accordion that are in the same table
       .next("tr").fadeOut(200) // toggles the content of the siblings
```

Comment: Excellent works a treat, however on selecting the headers is there a way to close the previous selection, as currently they are all open requiring manual close.

Comment: @Ebikeneser I updated my answer, hope it's clear enough to understand what it does

Comment: yep makes perfect sense +1